# count in OLS regression

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have a dataframe called `df`. In this dataframe I have a column named `true_or_false` which simply holds 1 or 0 values,  and a column `weekday` which takes the day of the week and represents it as a number 0-6.

I'm trying to make a linear regression model with statsmodels OLS that measures how much influence the day of the week has on the amount of 1 values in the `true_or_false` column.
This is the code that I have tried:

```
fit = ols('true_or_false ~ C(weekday)', data=df).fit() 
fit.summary()
```

I need to somehow make a count of how many times `true_or_false` holds the value 1 on a specific day of the week and pass that in the OLS formula. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure you need an OLS? If your response is binary, it should be a logistic regression?

Comment: My response isn't supposed to be binary. I want a count of the amount of 1 values. Not a classification of whether it is 1 or 0. Sorry if I don't understand.

Comment: IIUC, you can `new_df = df.groupby("weekday", as_index=False)["true_or_false"].sum()` and then regress over this `new_df`.

Comment: if you are summing up the 1s, then this is binomial distribution, and you use a logistic regression, because your response variable is that of proportions

Comment: In other words, you lose the information of 0s right? Are 0s useless ?

Comment: Yes, 0's are useless. I need to fill in the count per weekday as the dependent variable, and the weekday as independent variable in the OLS formula. @MustafaAydın 's answer helps but how do I make a new column for the dependent variable as it needs to be a column for the OLS formula to work.

Comment: @JdebMkay `true_or_false`, which will hold the sum per weekday, will be the dependent variable in `new_df`, no?

Comment: @MustafaAydın Yes you are right. But using linear regression I get an R2 value of 1.00. Which form of regression do you recommend? There is no linear growth in each week. But rather a curve upwards from Monday to Friday and then it drops on the weekend.

Comment: I'm not sure. Poisson regression maybe?